# DLL Dependencies in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I produced a DLL from a source project. Let's call is **sourceProject.dll**.

This project depends on **first.dll**, among other DLLs.

> ```
>    sourceProject.dll --> first.dll
> ```

When I run sourceProject.dll, I get an error that first.dll is "missing one or more project references".

If I understand correctly, sourceProject.dll is trying to use a class in first.dll, but apparently first.dll has a bad reference to one of its own DLLs. As a result, first.dll gets built again (at the run-time of sourceProject.dll), but it's built incorrectly. Finally, sourceProject.dll blows up because first.dll is bad.

Is that true?

thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Yes. If First.dll has errors, it won't be output.

Comment: so first.dll gets re-built when sourceProject.dll gets run?

Comment: Yes. If its not built or has changed, it will be rebuilt

Comment: Let's say I make a new class that belongs to sourceProject.dll. When I create that new class, sourceProject.dll (which references first.dll) will re-build first.dll? How does sourceProject.dll know if first.dll has changed?

Comment: It'll know about First.dll's changes only if its a project reference. If first.dll is coming from a third party (or an assembly reference), then it is already built. In this case, it (first.dll) cannot have a bad reference as it is built already.

Comment: what if first.dll is a C# wrapper that has only .lib references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I run sourceProject.dll

You cannot *run* DLLs in .NET. You use assemblies in applications which can be of different types (console, WinForms, ASP.NET, ...). So if `sourceProject.dll` depends on `first.dll` the application that uses `sourceProject.dll` need to have both assemblies in its working folder (current folder for desktop applications and bin folder for ASP.NET).

Comment: Let's say sourceProject.dll depends on: first.dll, second.dll, and third.dll.

Then sourceProject.dll needs to include **all** of the DLL's that first.dll, second.dll, and third.dll depend on?

Comment: @Kevin, it depends. If `sourceProject.dll` uses runtime type binding such as Reflection, you don't necessarily need to reference those dependencies. Of course in your final runnable application you need to reference them all. If you use static bindings then obviously you need to reference first.dll, second.dll, or sourceProject.dll will not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

My be your fist project is not included in the solution build. check the configuration manager from right click in the solution files.

I you want to work this was you have to build your first project (manual) before you build the other one.